# Youtube Api Data issue

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using v3 to get channel data from youtube. Api is working fine but there is an issue i am facing is that some dates data is missing for some channels.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which dates data is missing and then guess the channels too?

Comment: Yeah we are missing 4feb 8 feb data and channel name is "culture nation".

Comment: Can you please do me one more favor? Right now i am getting country code as "zz" while getting basic reports data from youtube. Why i am not getting correct country code?